# Shift a whole range of keys

Tags: mysql, time-series, dst, on-duplicate-key

I am working on time series data, for which the key column is a timestamp : *Time*. 
There are also many "value" columns for each row.

I am about to shift a whole range of my data by several hours (due to a daylight saving time issue).
For that, I will update the key of several rows, and it might result in some duplicate keys. I would like the duplicate keys on the edge of the date range to be ignore. I want the shifted range to override the old one.

I plan to do something like :

```
UPDATE IGNORE time_series_table 
SET time=time-<some_shift> 
WHERE <time in a date-range>
```

Here is the output of `describe <table>` for the time key :

```
Field     Type      Null Key     Default Extra
TimeMeas  datetime  NO   PRI     NULL
```

My question is : Will it shift all the keys at once, or will it try to shift each row one by one, resulting in massive duplicate keys wihthin the shifted range itself ?

Do you have a better way of doing this in mind ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say timestamp you mean the TIMESTAMP field type or an actual integer? Secondly, is this a UNIQUE key? The output of DESCRIBE or SHOW CREATE TABLE will be helpful.

Comment: I have added the output of the describe in the question.
Anyway. I got a good anwser yesterday : It was about using a temporary table to duplicate this one and using "REPLACE" / "ignore". I was about to vote for it, but it is gone today wihtout notification. 
This might be a bug of SO or the author deleting it for some reason.

Comment: What engine is used by the table? Is it InnoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will it shift all the keys at once, or will it try to shift each row one by one

It will shift all the keys at once.

> resulting in massive duplicate keys wihthin the shifted range itself ?

It just failed if any of primary key is duplicated.
With `update ignore`, it just skip silently.

This is my approach to fix this

```
/* create a temporary table to store matches records*/
create table tmp_table select time-<some_shift>, etc_cols....
from time_series_table 
where <time in a date-range>;
```

then

```
/* delete the matches in the original table */
delete from time_series_table where <time in a date-range>;
delete from time_series_table where <time in a date-range - some_shift>;
```

finally

```
/* at this point, there won't be any duplicate data */
/* so, insert back into original table */
insert into time_series_table select * from tmp_table;
optmize table time_series_table;
```